# Is *EOR an acceptable value for RMVBLANK option in CPYTOIMPF command?

Tags: ibm-midrange

According to the IBM website, the acceptable values for this option are *NONE, *LEADING, *TRAILING and *BOTH, and these are what shown in the help penal. But in the prompt (pressing F4), I have found an additional one which is *EOR. And I have tried to specify this value for the option and seems no error. So, is this one an acceptable value for RMVBLANK option? What is its purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's an acceptable value (assuming you have PTF SI47893 installed). It will remove trailing blanks from the End of Record. You can read more about this on the page about the PTF that supplies the new option:  http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas3c98e8af4ca6a3b2786257a8a0058032e

Comment: So why is there a difference between the help penal and the prompt screen? Under what circumstances would this value become necessary? Truncating blanks from the end of a record does not appear to be that useful for most of the times.

Comment: @God_of_Thunder - I have no idea why there is a difference between the help panel and the prompt screen - I would assume it's an oversight on IBM's part. I can't think of any circumstances off the top of my head where this option would be necessary - but IBM must have had enough customers ask for it to make it worth their time since they made it available via that PTF.

Comment: When IBM delivers functionality through an OS release, the command help gets updated - in over a hundred languages.  When they deliver functionality via a PTF, as in this case, the command help is often not updated because they don't want to go through the effort of all that translating.